# Imprimiendo con printdocument y printpreviewdialog c#

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Buen dia estoy imprimiendo el contenido de un richtextbox, esto en un printdocument y muestra una vista previa con un printpreview dialog, el problema es que me imprime todo el contenido del richtextbox en una sola linea, me gustaria saber si hay alguna forma de darle un salto de linea cuando este tope los margenes de la hoja.
Gracias :) 
[image: El boton azul activa el printpreviewdialog, que contiene el printdocument con el texto del richtextbox]

Comment: te refieres a la propiedad wordwrap?

Comment: pero el richtextbox no tiene ninguna propiedad llamada asi

Comment: Si cargas el documento con un editor, tipo Word, ¿tiene saltos de línea?